# AP physics 1 momentum and energy problem part 2 energy lost

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, momentum, spring

The first part, which I was able to solve was

A bullet of mass 7 g moving with an initial
speed 200 m/s is fired into and passes through
a block of mass 9 kg, as shown in the figure.
The block, initially at rest on a frictionless,
horizontal surface, is connected to a spring of
force constant 470 N/m. If the block moves a distance 0.45 cm to the
right after the bullet passed through it, find
the speed v at which the bullet emerges from
the block.
Answer in units of m/s.

I was able to solve this by finding the initial momentum of the bullet's mass times it's velocity and setting it equal to the mass of the block times its velocity(found through setting the spring energy equation equal to the kinetic energy equation) plus the bullets mass times the velocity and then solving the equation to get that it will be going 157.57 m/s

The second part is Find the magnitude of the energy lost in the
collision.
Answer in units of J

Which I would assume is initial  ke, which was 140 - the final of ~87, which equals 53. I also tried zero because of the law of conservation of energy. What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: Seems like you are missing the energy of the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final part of your question is a little unclear. I'll answer in general terms (have not double-checked your calculations).

The initial energy is entirely due to the bullet since the block is at rest. The final energy is due to the bullet and the spring. Note the block moves a certain distance and then comes to rest again (instantaneously) while its kinetic energy is converted into the spring's potential energy. Adding the bullet's final kinetic energy and the spring's potential energy, then subtracting from the initial energy, should yield the answer.

Comment: I tried it with that, however, the energy of the block is only ~ .0049 J. So it didn't change enough for the homework website to recognize it as a new answer.

Comment: @Student I rechecked your calculations and I suspect some rounding errors. For example my result for the final speed of the bullet is 158.19 m/s.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will go back through and try to recalculate it all. Much appreciated.                                                  Edit: I just redid it and it worked, I can't believe how silly of a mistake, thank you so much.